# Remote validation not working on large database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

put remote validation in mvc 5 and it working fine but if database is too large like i have 7000 records in database. It takes time(4 to 5 seconds) to show error but during this time if i submit the form, it submitted. How i can stop it?

Comment: Have you added `ServerSide` validation too? Have you checked the DB query plan?

Comment: yes. I added an action method isavailabe in which i get data from database and validate it

Comment: 7000 records is tiny. Look at indexing the appropriate properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.
Actually i have missed modelstate.isvalid in action method.